# How to pass particular test method name to testng.xml file from maven command

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I want pass particular test method to pass to testng.xml file using maven command and how to read that parameter in testng.xml

maven-surefire-plugin used in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Below is my testng.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
    <classes>
       <class name="com.ariveguru.tests.EServeSanityTest" />

    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as an argument from jenkins and update the following in the testng.xml

```
<test name="Automation Test Results" >
   <method-selectors>
       <method-selector><script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
         testngMethod.getMethodName().contains(System.getProperty("testToRun"))
       ]]></script></method-selector>
   </method-selectors>
  <packages>
       <package name="com.mycompany.*"></package>
   </packages> 
  </test>
```

From jenkins add one more argument -DtestToRun=testToTest

Comment: Also don't forget to add the maven repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.beanshell/bsh

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do with the test method's name?

If it is to include/exclude certain tests, the Surefire Plugin allows for [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), but not for individual methods. To achieve this you could move the methods in question into their own test class, if this is feasible.

Comment: If it is through mvn I can use "mvn -Dtest=Sanitytest#CaseCreation clean test" But in jenkins above commnand is not working so I added testng.xml to give try in different way

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't mention Jenkins in your question and it isn't tagged accordingly either. Where did you add `testng.xml`? What is the basic config of your Jenkins job? I'm sorry again but if the actual information drop just gradually it's hard to give an appropriate answer.